# Using closest for getting form object

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, dom, client-side

Recently, I am reviewing client side code written by another programmer. I am surprised with code which is used for getting form object.

**HTML for Login Form**

```
<form id="frm_login" action="">
  <input type="text" name="username" id="username">
  <input type="password" name="pwd" id="pwd">
</form>
```

He has used following code to get form object

```
$frm = $("input[type='password']").closest("form");
```

But there is simple code for getting form object which I prefer:

```
$frm = $("#frm_login");
```

Is there any reason to use closest to get form object in above scenario?

I would really like to know if there is any performance issues.

Comment: You shouldn't notice performance issues either way.  They're both fast.  `$("#frm_login")` may be slightly faster.

Comment: Why closest when you have ID selector..

Comment: I am more convinced with my method but I would just like to know why he has used that method.

Comment: one possibility is that initially form had no id thus he used closest. I feel application evolved gradually. One thing is sure if he how to use closest() he definitely know how to use id-selector

Comment: @Satpal : Yes,  if he know how to use closest() he definitely know how to use id-selector. So, I am confused about his approach.

Comment: closet is mainly useful when the form/element is dynamically generated     rather than using id..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The id of element is supposed to be unique. If there is **single** form on page then there is no need to relate it to its parent using closest. It would have more sense if the form does not have id. Getting form through id seem more straight forward and fast.

If there are **multiple** forms and one have to get the form in which the element exists then using closest make sense. This could be understood with the following example.

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/8aXvE/)**

**Html**

```
<form id="frm_login1" action="">
    <input type="text" name="username" id="username1" />
    <input type="password" name="pwd" id="pwd1">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="text" class="myInputClass" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
<form id="frm_login2" action="">
    <input type="text" name="username" id="username2">
    <input type="password" name="pwd" id="pwd2">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="text" class="myInputClass" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

**Javascript**

```
$("input[type='password']").closest("form").each(function(){
   alert($(this).find('.myInputClass').val()); 
});
```

Comment: Still the id will be unique for each of multiple forms. Why not to use  $("#frm_id") for multiple forms too?

Comment: Thanks Adil but that is not the case.

Comment: You are welcome. The code you showed is single line and does not give enough information why he would have used it. But I showed you a possible use.

Answer (score 0):

as others said, if you have id, no need to use closest to get parent form. and using id is faster.

HOWEVER, in some cases you need to use closest to get form, for example, if you write a universal function for validating every password input in every form, in this case you don't like to get forms by ids and search for its childes passwordfields to prevent auto submitting, so i guess the guy who wrote the code, is doing this(a function which validates passwords before submit)

```
$("input[type='password']").each(function(){
   $frm = .closest("form");
   $frm.submit(function(event){
       if( not valid password){
          ......
          return false;
       }
   });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

If there is single form on page then there is no need to relate it to its parent using closest. It would have more sense if the form does not have id. Getting form through id seem more straight forward and fast.

But The `Closest()` method is very cool and very useful, especially when you start to deal with event delegation in which events are trapped at a higher level in the node tree than are the elements that triggered the event.

the `closest()` method searches through these elements and their ancestors in the DOM tree and constructs a new jQuery object from the matching elements.

Comment: Thanks GovindaRajbhar. I know how does closest work but I am confused with his approach to above problem. There is unique id for the each form.